# Apache 2.2 can't setup a VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to set up a new virtual host `newsletter.mydomain.com`.

I'm also using `mod_proxy` to route all HTTP traffic to my application server (with the IP of 
1.1.1.1).

`mod_proxy` works great but I'm having a real hard trouble setting up the virtual host:

When I try browsing my VHOST, all I get is **my main website** (instead, for instance, the DocumentRoot i've set to it, or on another try - a ProxyPass declaration that should route traffic)

Here's a brief snippet of my httpd.conf file

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost _default_:80

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

ServerName www.mydomain.com:80

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>


<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName newsletter.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://1.1.1.1:8080/Newsletter/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://1.1.1.1:8080/Newsletter/
</VirtualHost> 

ProxyPass / http://1.1.1.1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://1.1.1.1/
```

Main website works gr8 - Virtual host - de nada! any ideas on this issue?
(Using Windows 2008 server R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `_default_:80` to `*:80` in both places.  The `_default_` clause is specifically *not* used for `NameVirtualHost` routed VHosts.

However, this still won't work as you expect.  As soon as you declare `*:80` a `NameVirtualHost`, your "default" site will never be displayed.  (per: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost)

What you want is something more like this:

```
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"
Listen 80

# Route all traffic based on Host: header
NameVirtualHost *:80

ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

ServerName www.mydomain.com:80

# This will never be used:
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

# All non-matching Host: headers use the first VirtualHost:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ProxyPass / http://1.1.1.1/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://1.1.1.1/
</VirtualHost>

# Specific VirtualHost for "newsletter.mydomain.com":
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName newsletter.mydomain.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://1.1.1.1:8080/Newsletter/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://1.1.1.1:8080/Newsletter/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Tested that - no luck

Comment: @Shai, I update with some new information after posting my initial one-liner.

Comment: I got it solved a few minutes ago, your answer matches the solution I've come up with. Thanks!